getauxval can't cowork with ifunc
This question is derived from here, however, it is still a totally new question.
After the mentioned question, I have the following code. It can select between memcpy and my_memcpy by use_embed.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
static int use_embed = 1;
void *my_memcpy (void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    return dst;
}
static void * (*resolve_memcpy (void))(void *, const void *, size_t)
{
    if(use_embed == 1) {
        return memcpy;
    } else {
        return my_memcpy;
    }
}
void *memcpy2 (void *, const void *, size_t) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_memcpy")));
#define memcpy memcpy2
// extern void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t);
int main() {
    int source = 5;
    int dest = 6;
    memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(source));
    printf("%d %d\n", use_embed, dest);
    return 0;
}

However, I want to use getauxval to decide which version to be used, so I have the following code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>

#ifndef HWCAP2_MTE
#define HWCAP2_MTE (1 << 18)
#endif
#ifndef HWCAP_SVE
#define HWCAP_SVE (1 << 22)
#endif
#ifndef AT_HWCAP2
#define AT_HWCAP2 26
#endif
#ifndef AT_HWCAP
#define AT_HWCAP 16
#endif
/// check if MTE is supported in current environment
static int mte_supported(void)
{
    return (getauxval(AT_HWCAP2) & HWCAP2_MTE);
}
/// check if SVE is supported in current environment
static int sve_supported(void)
{
    return (getauxval(AT_HWCAP) & HWCAP_SVE);
}

void *my_memcpy (void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    return dst;
}
static void * (*resolve_memcpy (void))(void *, const void *, size_t)
{
    if(mte_supported() != 0) {
        return my_memcpy;
    }
    if(sve_supported() != 0) {
        return my_memcpy;
    }
    return my_memcpy;
}
void *memcpy2 (void *, const void *, size_t) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_memcpy")));
#define memcpy memcpy2
// extern void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t);
int main() {
    int source = 5;
    int dest = 6;
    memcpy2(&dest, &source, sizeof(source));
    printf("%d\n", dest);
    return 0;
}

It segfaults when built with clang15, for the same reason(related to PLT) mentioned in my previous question. To elaborate, the first jump in the PLT section for getauxval@plt points to neither _dl_runtime_resolve nor read access point to getauxval.
My question is:

How to fix the code? I mean ifunc should have foreseen this problem. It must have already provide some solutions which I don't know.
If there is no solution by ifunc, do we have some workarounds on the PLT level? Like LD_BIND_NOW or something.

==== EDIT ====
clang --version
clang version 15.0.7 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project 8dfdcc7b7bf66834a761bd8de445840ef68e4d1a)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.x86_64 (mockbuild@dal1-prod-builder001.bld.equ.rockylinux.org) (gcc (GCC) 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2), GNU ld version 2.35.2-24.el9) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov 18 02:06:38 UTC 2022


"It segfaults when built with clang15" -- works for me using Debian clang version 15.0.7 or Debian clang version 16.0.6 (19).

I ran into this too, and found the solution in the System V ABI for AArch64: the resolver function is actually passed the hwcaps as arguments, removing the need to call getauxval (which as you've found, isn't necessarily safe to do at the time the resolver is called).
Here's a modification of your code to demonstrate this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>

#ifndef HWCAP2_MTE
#define HWCAP2_MTE (1 << 18)
#endif
#ifndef HWCAP_SVE
#define HWCAP_SVE (1 << 22)
#endif
/// check if MTE is supported in current environment
static int mte_supported(unsigned long hwcap2)
{
    return (hwcap2 & HWCAP2_MTE);
}
/// check if SVE is supported in current environment
static int sve_supported(unsigned long hwcap)
{
    return (hwcap & HWCAP_SVE);
}

void *my_memcpy_mte(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("MTE\n");
    return dst;
}

void *my_memcpy_sve(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("SVE\n");
    return dst;
}

void *my_memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("fallback\n");
    return dst;
}

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long hwcap;
    unsigned long hwcap2;
} ifunc_arg;

static void * (*resolve_memcpy (unsigned long hwcap, const ifunc_arg *extra))(void *, const void *, size_t)
{
    if ((hwcap & (1ULL << 62)) && mte_supported(extra->hwcap2) != 0) {
        return my_memcpy_mte;
    }
    if(sve_supported(hwcap) != 0) {
        return my_memcpy_sve;
    }
    return my_memcpy;
}
void *memcpy2 (void *, const void *, size_t) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_memcpy")));
#define memcpy memcpy2
// extern void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t);
int main() {
    int source = 5;
    int dest = 6;
    memcpy2(&dest, &source, sizeof(source));
    printf("%d\n", dest);
    return 0;
}

